# JavaScript Standard Style does not recognize jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I need to setup jest and [JavaScript Standard Style](https://standardjs.com/) to work together when using `npm test`.

Now when I am running `npm test` the test fails because JavaScript Standard Style thrown an errors:

```
'test' is not defined.
'expect' is not defined.
```

I can work around this issue by defining in my package.json file some global for jest.

```
"standard": {
    "globals": [
        "fetch",
        "test",
        "expect"
    ]
}
```

But definitely I do not think it is a good solution.

In my test case sum.test.js

```
const sum = require('./sum')    
test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3)
})
```

In my package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "standard && jest",
}
```

Question:

- How to configure JavaScript Standard Style so it does not thrown an error when used with jest?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I was able to find a solution.

In package.json

```
"standard": {
  "env": [ "jest" ]
}
```

Or in the test case:

```
/* eslint-env mocha */
```

Comment: I guess `/* eslint-env mocha */` should be `/* eslint-env jest */`

Comment: In my case, I wanted to use [`fail`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526098/614523) but it was not recognised.  I added `"globals": [ "fail" ]` to the `standard` entry package.json as per the original question and it seemed to work, but I believe this will allow `fail` in all files, not just tests.

Comment: It's really better in the test case, however for a quick fix when you are starting a toy project it's not bad at all having the environments defined globally.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.eslintrc.js` file, include the following setting and you'll be good to go.

```
"env": {
  "node": true,
  "jest": true
}
```

If you are using a `.eslintrc` or a `.eslintrc.json` file, please use appropriate syntax.