# Is "fail" supposed to work in a catch block within a jest test? Or: *why* isnt it working within this catch block?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to use try/catch with jest test and discovered some behavior I do not understand. My expectation is that `fail('msg')` should work within a try/catch block within a `test("", () => { // fail should be available everywhere here }}`

This makes me think I do not understand try/catch the way I think I do.

Here is some code to demonstrate

```
import cats from "./script";

describe("try catch doesnt work for fail", () => {
    test("wherein we see fail doesn't work in try catch", () => {
        try {
            const x = cats()
            fail("cats")
            throw new Error("this fails")
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err)
            fail("isn't working in catch")
        }
    })
})
```

This errors with this message:

```
  ● try catch doesnt work for fail › wherein we see fail doesn't work in try catch

    ReferenceError: fail is not defined

       9 |         } catch(err){
      10 |             console.log(err)
    > 11 |             fail("isn't working in catch")
         |             ^
      12 |         }
      13 |     })
```

Notice that it doesnt say that about the `fail("cats")` within the try block.

What is going on?

Note this isn't blocking me from progressing, more like I'm just curious in what way I am wrong about Jest, and maybe JavaScript too.

I discovered this while working on a project:

```
    ReferenceError: fail is not defined

      73 |             expect(true).toBe(true); 
                  // if "fail" isnt defined, why is "expect"?
      74 |             console.log(err);
    > 75 |             fail("some error2");
         |             ^
      76 |         }
      77 |     });
      78 | });
```

Here is some info that is probably irrelevant but required to set this up locally:

`.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
  }
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "sadf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "babel-jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest": "^29.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

edit: there is some similar question about how to make a test fail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176642/in-jest-how-can-i-make-a-test-fail)

I am not asking about how to make a test fail. I know that: You use `fail()` somewhere it is defined.

The question is *what is going on* to make `fail()` exposed within `try` but not within `catch`? I learned here that it is intentionally not exposed within a catch block. However, I have not yet learned how exposing `fail()` within try but not catch has been accomplished. That part is still a mystery to me.

I hope I'm not asking too much: No one needs to find out *exactly* how jest has arranged for this to be the case, as that might require a lot of digging. It's more like "how could this be accomplished?"

edit2: IMO my original intent, namely "learn why `fail()` is available within try but not within catch" has not been addressed at all by the "duplicate" linked.

Comment: how can you fail in the catch -- it is not part of the try block -- there is nothing to fail.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11698

Comment: so "fail" isn't defined in the catch block intentionally...? I just dont get why "fail" is defined within try, which is within a test, when it isn't defined within catch, which is ... also in a test.

Answer (score 0):

## `fail` is undefined in **both** the `try` and the `catch` blocks ([Jest 27 removed that method](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/11698)).

The error message looks confusing since the code snippet shows a different line than the one causing the original definition lookup error (evidenced by the stack trace).

If you take a closer look at the exact error message printed out by the `console.log` in your `catch` block (see below), you'll notice that the stack trace indicates that it could not find the definition for `fail` on line 7, which is its attempted invocation in the `try` block.

```
console.log
  ReferenceError: fail is not defined
      at Object.fail (index.test.js:7:13)   <--- HERE IS WHERE `fail` WAS NOT DEFINED!
      at Promise.then.completed (node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:298:28)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at callAsyncCircusFn (node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:231:10)
      ... [omitted for brevity]

    at Object.log (index.test.js:10:21)
```

## Use a [custom matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers) instead to force test failures

At the time of writing, [Jest does not provide an equivalent to `fail`](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/11698), so you have to provide your own. I use a custom `expect` matcher

```js
function toFail(_, message) {
  this.dontThrow();  // Support failing in try/catch blocks
  return {
    pass: false,
    message: () => (message ? message : 'fails by .toFail() assertion'),
  };
}

expect.extend({ toFail });
```

You can then use your custom `toFail` matcher in tests

```js
test("my test", () => {
  expect().toFail("this test fails unconditionally");
})
```

---

## Bonus: Scoping function visibility with Babel

> The question is what is going on to make fail() exposed within try but not within catch?

You also asked *how* someone could make a function globally available in a `try` but not in a `catch`. As shown above, *Jest does not do this*, but this section describes how such an effect might be achieved.

Since your example project uses Babel -- which enables rewriting code -- a prankster could [use a plugin to rewrite](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins#plugin-development) `fail("message")` to `throw new ReferenceError("fail is not defined")` whenever it occurs in a `catch` block

***WARNING:** Babel plugins are a powerful tool. The code below is an abuse of that power for educational purposes and should not be used in any serious program.*

```js
// plugin.mjs
export default function break_fail_in_catch({ types: t }) {
  const CatchVisitor = { // Inside `catch` blocks
    ExpressionStatement(path, state) {
      if (path.node.expression.callee.name === 'fail') {
        // Replace `fail` function calls with throwing `ReferenceError`
        path.replaceWith(
          t.throwStatement(t.newExpression(
            t.identifier("ReferenceError"), 
            [t.stringLiteral("fail is not defined")]
          ))
        )
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    visitor: {
      CatchClause(path, state) {
        path.traverse(CatchVisitor)
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Running the plugin on the try/catch block from your example shows the expected change.

```js
// test.mjs
import babel from '@babel/core';
import break_fail_in_catch from './plugin.mjs'

const code = `
try {
  const x = cats()
  fail("cats")
  throw new Error("this fails")
} catch(err){
  console.log(err)
  fail("isn't working in catch")
}
`;

const result = babel.transformSync(code, {
  plugins: [break_fail_in_catch]
});

console.log(result.code);
```

```
$ node test.mjs
try {
  const x = cats();
  fail("cats");
  throw new Error("this fails");
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  throw new ReferenceError("fail is not defined");  // <-- Notice the change
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't fail in the catch.  It is not part of the try block -- there is nothing to fail.  You want to use throw() instead.

Comment: I believe OP is trying to use Jest's `fail()` function which (if actually available) you should be able to call anywhere

Comment: @Phil  The fail fast feature of Jest/jasmine is intended to have the test fail.  But when you are in the catch block the test has already failed -- so there is nothing to do.  it is functionally the using throw should achieve the same result.  Looking at github the platform clears it when the first error is thrown

Comment: That makes sense to me and partially answers my question. I now understand that `fail()` intentionally does not exist in `catch`. The remaining ignorance is: *how* is this accomplished? Even an explanation like "well I'm not reading the entire Jest module to explain it to you but it could be accomplished this way..." would be enlightening. That part is a mystery to me too and is part of my learning objective.

Comment: @plutownium -- it is implemented in jasmine which is inlcuded in jest -- and yes I did scan the github code.  basically the dynamic nature of javascript allows you to "null out" the function in the current object

Comment: There are plenty of reasons for wanting to `fail` in a `catch`. For example, `fail` if an exception of type `MyEasyToHandleError` is caught, e.g. because it should have been handled automatically by the code under test.

Comment: @thehale -- then you should use `throw()`  "Rethrowing" in a catch is a common design pattern.

Comment: @Hogan, Rethrowing definitely has its uses (e.g. provide additional context/improve an error message), but, respectfully, common =/= always the right choice. After all, rethrowing *everything* is functionally equivalent to having no try/catch at all (i.e. the application crashes). One concrete example where *not rethrowing* is desirable is the common [Retry pattern in distributed systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/retry).

Comment: @thehale -- sure (I agree with everything you said).  Here we aren't talking about every case, we are talking about the case given by the OP which should be re-thrown or be refactored.