# Element is possibly 'null' error in test. How to correctly write expect in test using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I'm using RTL and have a test:

```
describe('Image component', () => {
  it('renders avatar', () => {
    render(<Image {...args} />);
    const element = document.querySelector('img');
    expect(element.src).toContain(args.image);
  });
});
```

After switching on `strictNullChecks`, I got error on final line saying `'element' is possibly 'null'`. Yes, I can make a null check before `expect` line, but doesn't it render pointless test then? Because if `element` won't be found, I want test to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be handled by using Ts type assertion.

Like:

```
const element = document.querySelector('img') as HTMLImageElement;
```

OR

```
const element = <HTMLImageElement>document.querySelector('img');
```

Another approach is to check for element truthiness else fail the test

```
if (element) {
      expect(element.src).toContain(args.image);
    } else {
      fail('Image element not found');
    }
```

Check related [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176642/in-jest-how-can-i-make-a-test-fail)

Comment: Thanks! You definitely pointed me to right direction. In my case I used `throw new Error('Image element not found!');`. There was also an option to use `expect(element?.src).toContain(args.image);`, but after some testing I like more version with custom error, as it was providing more information about what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `querySelector` as much as possible (advised by the creator of React Testing Library himself https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-container-to-query-for-elements).

If you want to test your image has the correct `src` attribute :

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

...

describe('Image component', () => {
  it('renders avatar', () => {
    render(<Image {...args} />);
    const element = screen.getByRole('img');
    expect(element).toHaveAttribute('src', args.image);
  });
});
```